# Questions about how to call Nodes work in Java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I want some clarification wether what I understood is correct or not.

1. When I call "Node" as a datatype within the class it's referring it
   as an **object of my class** "Node"
2. When I use "Node" as a datatype outside the class (Ex - Node root)
   it's saying it only accepts datatypes of "Node" and it also **doesn't
   effect** the Node class itself since it's not one of its variables
3. When you create a "Node" variable outside of its class it
   **inherits** all of the class fields (key, name, leftChild, rightChild)
4. Someone once told me straight up calling the class("Node") is
   somewhat of a **quick form** of doing - How much of that is true?

   Example - Node node = new Node();

**Note** - These are snippets codes for a Binary Search Tree

```
Node root;

class Node
{
    int key;
    String name;

    Node leftChild;
    Node rightChild;

    Node(int key, String name)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        //year //team name
        return key + " - " + name;
    }

}
```

Comment: All 4 of your question don#t make any sense at all. Please read some basic tutorial on what classes are and what references are and then clarify the question.

Comment: I think a binary search tree might be too complex for your question, which is the basics of object instantiation

Comment: You seem a little confused, @confusedpanda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. When I call "Node" as a datatype within the class its referring it as an object of my class "Node"
> 2. When I use "Node" as a datatype outside the class (Ex - Node root) its saying it only accepts datatypes of "Node" and it also doesn't
>      effect the Node class itself since its not one of its variables `Node
>      root` - declare a variable `n` of type `Node`

I'll get to #1 later, but I want to focus on this statement

> it doesn't effect the Node class itself

No, nothing affects the class, because the class maintains no state. The instance of the variable does, such as `root`, `leftChild`, and `rightChild`. Each of these are *instances* of one `Node` class. Updating one does not affect the others.

> 3. When you create a "Node" variable outside of its class it inherits all of the class fields (key, name, leftChild, rightChild)

Not sure what you mean by "inherit", but those are member variables (or fields) of an instance of a `Node`, so sure, they are properties/attributes of the instance that you can say "inherit", but don't confuse that with the actually terminology of "inheritance" in Object Oriented Programming

> 4. Someone once told me straight up calling the class("Node") is somewhat of a quick form of doing - How much of that is true?

Quick form of what? `Node n;` and `Node n = new Node();` are **not** the same. The later initializes the variable, the former only declares.

And using `new Node()` isn't "calling a class", it is instead "constructing a class", because you are "calling the constructor". So, back to #1, yes, that seems like a valid statement.